# JSON Ignore property just in POST in a REST Service

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a service that is something near to REST, but not really REST.
I usually have an object for each method in my services, but in this case I can't (management restrictions, not technical).
I am facing a problem. I have two methods with theese signatures:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyViewModel GetTheViewModel() { ... }
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public void ModifyTheViewModel(MyViewModel input)
```

Now, what I need is that some properties in `MyViewModel` are visible and serializated in `GET`, but I want to hide them from the `POST` method. Do you know if it is possible?

Thank you

Comment: Create a base class with common fields and two separate class for each methods for only fields you want to expose

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally create a separate model to represent the data that you want to be able to modify. Once you pass on the `MyViewModel` outside the content of the `ModifyTheViewModel` it has no understanding of why certain fields are `null` etc...

```
public class MyViewModel : MyModel
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public string LastName { get; set; }
}


[HttpGet]
public MyViewModel GetTheViewModel() { ... }


[HttpPost]
public void ModifyTheViewModel(MyModel input)
```

Comment: I agree with you... I usually separate model too... but I can't... Even if I play with inheritance, it's like I have two different classes. I had hoped something like `JsonIgnore` existed